# Is there a simple way to hookup grideye(AMG88xx) to rpi3 and program to get the pixel data?

Tags: python, i2c

I have a problem using busio and CircuitPython modules.

Example code-

```
import time
import busio
import board
import adafruit_amg88xx
i2c_bus = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
amg = adafruit_amg88xx.AMG88XX(i2c_bus)
while True:
for row in amg.pixels:
#pad to 1 decimal place
print(['{0:.1f}'.format(temp) for temp in row])
print("")
print("\n")
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to stack overflow. We are happy to help, you and the many other people who may have the same problem and will end up reading this question. We need to know __what__ problem do you have in order to do it, a piece of code is not enough, you should explain what do you expect, how is it not doing what you expect, or any error you may get when executing it

Comment: Explain your problem a bit more please and add an expected output.